# Language clarification in an article about filters

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, filters

I started reading these [notes](http://www.efnet-math.org/%7Edavid/mathematics/filters.pdf).

After enumerating four properties of a filter $\mathcal F$ in a topological space $(X,\tau)$

> (1) $X\in\mathcal F$;
>
> (2) $V\in\mathcal F\wedge V\subseteq W\implies W\in\mathcal F$,
>
> (3) $U,V\in\mathcal F\implies U\cap V\in\mathcal F $,
>
> (4) $\varnothing\notin \mathcal F$
> ,

the author says the following:
"Note that ﬁlters are closed under ﬁnite intersection as well as pairwise (by induction)".

I can't seem to find another interpretation for this sentence rather than "(filters are closed under finite intersection) and (the intersection of a pair of filters is still a filter) and (proof is made by induction)". It doesn't make much sense to talk particularly about a pair of filters after generalizing the property to the finite number case.

I'm not an english native speaker, so I suppose I'm misunderstanding what's being said, could someone help here? Thanks!

Comment: @DanielFischer You're correct. Instead of "filters" I tought about the "family of all filters on $X$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning, I'm convinced, is that the family $\mathcal{F}$ (of subsets of $X$) is closed under finite intersections, as well as pairwise intersections. That is, if $A_k \in \mathcal{F}$ for $1 \leqslant k \leqslant n$, where $n$ is an arbitrary natural number, then also

$$\bigcap_{k=1}^n A_k \in \mathcal{F},$$

which is "$\mathcal{F}$ is closed under finite intersections", and the special case of pairwise intersections is $n = 2$, which is axiom $(3)$ of the definition of a filter. The general case is proved by induction on $n$ using the pairwise intersection property.

It is, however, indeed an awkward wording of the intended information.

The fact that the intersection of any family of filters is again a filter, is used less, and since that intersection property holds not only for finite families of filters but for arbitrary families, it is very unlikely that the author meant that interpretation.